# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property

Tags: html5, json, angular, typescript

Tenho de clicar um botao em uma pagina html e acionar uma função no component.ts chamada metodoTeste, porém estou recendo uma mensagem de erro(imagem de erro)

**imagem do front**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { BaseComponent } from '../../base.component'
import { Atividade } from '../../agenda/models/atividade';
import { CurrencyUtils } from '../../utils/currency-utils';

@Component({
    selector: 'lista-pagamento-cielo',
    templateUrl: './templates/lista-pagamento-cielo.html',
    styleUrls: ['../../dashboard/styles/dashboard.css'],
    providers: []
})

export class ListaPagamentoCielo extends BaseComponent {

     constructor() { super() }

     title = 'Tela Cancelamento Cielo';

     cliente = [
        {Holder:'TRTPE', ReceivedDate:'2018-09-20 16:22:51',Tid:'0920042251610',Amount:'9000',PaymentId:'73626a76-7601-4902-a884-bab3d1b4cc8e'},
        {Holder:'BC Advogados', ReceivedDate:'2018-09-20 15:58:38',Tid:'0920040857659',Amount:'9000',PaymentId:'cb052369-0fcc-45d3-b35c-39d2829a9d7b'},
        {Holder:'OABr', ReceivedDate:'2018-09-20 16:22:33',Tid:'0920042251610',Amount:'9000',PaymentId:'8327b48d-fcf8-4088-8418-79388ac8dfc3'}
     ];

    //funcao  para chamar enviar tid para cancelar 
    metodoTeste(cliente){
        console.log(cliente.Tid)
    }
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="portlet  portlet-fit white" [ngBusy]="busy">
    <div class="portlet-body">
        <!-- <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-8 text-right">
                <span style="border-left:1px solid #eee;margin-left:2px;"> &nbsp;</span>
            </div>
        </div> -->
        <span> <b>{{title}}</b></span>


        <div class="table-scrollable">
            <table class="table table-hover table-responsive" id="listaComprasCielo" role="grid" style="width:100%;">
                <thead class="">
                    <tr role="row">
                        <th>Cliente</th>
                        <th>Data</th>
                        <th>TID</th>
                        <th>Valor da venda </th>
                        <th>Acao</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr role="row"  *ngFor="let clientes of cliente">
                        <!-- NPU / CIV -->
                        <td>{{clientes.Holder}}</td>
                        <td>{{clientes.ReceivedDate | date: 'dd/mm/yyyy'}}</td>
                        <td>{{clientes.Tid}}</td>
                        <td>{{clientes.Amount/100 | currency:'R$' }}</td>

                          <!-- Acao -->
                        <td>
                          <button (click)="metodoTeste(clientes.TID)">Cancelar Cielo</button>
                        </td>
                        <!-- CLIENTE(HOLDING) -->
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Imagem do erro**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Troque `console.log(cliente.Tid)` por `console.log(cliente)` e veja o que mostra.

Comment: você já está passando clientes.tid no método teste e lá você está tentando pegar a propriedade denovo, sendo que você em tese já passou só ela, outra coisa você está passando clientes.TID, typescript é case insensitive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está chamando na declaração um objeto e na hora de chamar está passando o ID ...

```
<button (click)="metodoTeste(clientes)">Cancelar Cielo</button>
```

Faça essa tentativa, acredito que vai funcionar